# Trying to work with OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I am trying this simple code:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabasePool;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx;

public class ProgramOrientDB {
  private static TestObjectFiller filler = new TestObjectFiller();

  private static interface DBCallback<T> {
    T call(OObjectDatabaseTx db) throws Exception;
  }

  private static <T> T execWithDB(DBCallback<T> cb) throws Exception {
    OObjectDatabaseTx db;
    try {
      db = OObjectDatabasePool.global().acquire("local:c:/tmp/odb", "admin", "admin");
    } catch (OStorageException exc) {
      db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("local:c:/tmp/odb");
      db.create();
    }
    try {
      return cb.call(db);
    } finally {
      db.close();
    }
  }

  private static TestObject dump(TestObject o) {
    System.out.println(o);
    return o;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = run.exec("cmd /c del /s/q c:\\tmp\\odb");
    pr.waitFor();

    execWithDB(new DBCallback<Void>() {
      @Override
      public Void call(OObjectDatabaseTx db) throws Exception {
        db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(TestObject.class);
        dump((TestObject)db.save(filler.randomFill(db.newInstance(TestObject.class))));
        return null;
      }
    });
    execWithDB(new DBCallback<Void>() {
      @Override
      public Void call(OObjectDatabaseTx db) throws Exception {
        db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(TestObject.class);
        for (TestObject o : (List<TestObject>)db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<TestObject>("select * from TestObject"))) {
          System.out.println(o);
        }
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

It outputs to the console this:

```
TestObject{prop1: 'captivation', prop2: 'Caribbean's', prop3: -1912492199, prop4: 0.9350339155517686, prop5: false}
TestObject{prop1: 'null', prop2: 'null', prop3: 0, prop4: 0.0, prop5: false}
```

Whereas I have expected the first line to be output twice. Can anyone spot what's the problem with it?

**EDIT1**

Here is TestObject.java:

```
public class TestObject {
  private String m_prop1;
  private String m_prop2;
  private int m_prop3;
  private double m_prop4;
  private boolean m_prop5;

  public String getProp1() {
    return m_prop1;
  }

  public void setProp1(String prop1) {
    m_prop1 = prop1;
  }

  public String getProp2() {
    return m_prop2;
  }

  public void setProp2(String prop2) {
    m_prop2 = prop2;
  }

  public int getProp3() {
    return m_prop3;
  }

  public void setProp3(int prop3) {
    m_prop3 = prop3;
  }

  public double getProp4() {
    return m_prop4;
  }

  public void setProp4(double prop4) {
    m_prop4 = prop4;
  }

  public boolean isProp5() {
    return m_prop5;
  }

  public void setProp5(boolean prop5) {
    m_prop5 = prop5;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("TestObject");
    sb.append("{prop1: '").append(m_prop1).append('\'');
    sb.append(", prop2: '").append(m_prop2).append('\'');
    sb.append(", prop3: ").append(m_prop3);
    sb.append(", prop4: ").append(m_prop4);
    sb.append(", prop5: ").append(m_prop5);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

**EDIT2**

Changed TestObject.java to include the following field:

```
  @javax.persistence.Id
  private Object id;
```

And added to toString(). Now the program prints:

```
TestObject{id: 'null', prop1: 'gnaw', prop2: 'fishermen', prop3: -322577834, prop4: 0.7442149523357203, prop5: true}
TestObject{id: 'null', prop1: 'null', prop2: 'null', prop3: 0, prop4: 0.0, prop5: false}
```

Which is not much better.

**EDIT3**

The problem is that `OObjectProxyMethodHandler.invoke()` is not called, even though `db.newInstance` does return a proxy and I set the properties using `TestObject.setXXX` methods. I have no idea why the handler is not called.

**EDIT4**

OK, the problem with the handler was that the method filter implemented by `OObjectMethodFilter` was checking that methods are backed by fields named using a certain naming scheme. The `TestObject` class does not follow that scheme - it uses the `m_` prefix for the private fields, which fails the filter test. Removed the prefix, now `OObjectProxyMethodHandler.invoke()` is called. However, the final result is still the same. Investigating further.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty strange the output has no the RID for records. Have you removed them for layout purpose?

Comment: Could not find a detailed guide on how to start, hence stupid mistakes. It was not clear to me how to do it right just from reading https://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Object2RecordJavaBinding

Comment: Added the Id field, still no dice.

Comment: Add the getter/setter also for Id.

Comment: Really? I will try, but https://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Object2RecordJavaBinding#How_it_works? clearly states: "DON'T CREATE GETTER/SETTER FOR IT TO PREVENT THE CHANGING BY THE USER APPLICATION"

Comment: I have just tried it - does not work. The id remains null after  `db.save`.

Comment: BTW, using `ODatabaseDocumentTx` does work. But I want to use the object binding.

Comment: In `OObjectDatabaseTx.save` there is a line `ODocument savedRecord = underlying.save(record, iClusterName, iMode, iForceCreate, iRecordCreatedCallback, iRecordUpdatedCallback);` The returned savedRecord seems OK. The `_fieldValues` and `_recordId` fields are set properly. Still `TestObject.id` remains null and querying returns an empty `TestObject` instance.

Comment: The getter/setter for Id was just as a try. Here the best guy is Luca Molino, the original author of POJO binding. I'm going to forward the URL of such thread.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason that this isn't working as you expected is that you're not using the TestObject setter/getter methods to set/retrieve the field values.  The OrientDB Java proxy objects "intercept" the set/get calls to perform necessary management behind-the-scenes; in particular, the setters will mark fields as dirty (for `db.save()`) and the getters will fetch lazy-loaded field data from the db (fields will have default values until loaded).  As you noted, it's expected that the setters/getters follow Java naming conventions with respect to the field names.

In your example program, you're populating the sample TestObject *after* it's been proxied by the DB, in `filler.randomFill(db.newInstance(TestObject.class))`. As a result, your randomFill must use setters when populating the TestObject's fields.

Similarly, your TestObject.toString() output is showing null/default values because you're (most likely) directly accessing the fields instead of using the getters.  The proxy is lazy-loading field data, so the field won't be populated until the load is triggered by calling the corresponding get method.

When I modify your test code to use setter/getter methods on TestObject, I get the same line output twice, as expected.

See also: [OrientDB Object2RecordJavaBinding](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Object-2-Record-Java-Binding)

Comment: Yes, the behavior is caused by the lazy loaded of field data. The object fields are `null`until the proper getter method is used (also inside other methods of the proxied object). This should be the accepted answer.