# Importing Java OrientDB Packages

Tags: java, orientdb, database, nosql

I am not new to Java per se... or looking up answers for myself.  But for some reason I cannot import the OrientDB packages.  I have looked at the following simple examples:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Java-Tutorial:-Introduction

[Trying to work with OrientDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502441/trying-to-work-with-orientdb)

example:

```
   import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.TransactionalGraph;
   import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;
```

but I keep getting "package * does not exist" for any import combination I use.

I was under the impression that all I needed to get started was 'orientdb-community-1.*/lib/orientdb-core-1.*.jar'.  Where is 'com', 'tinkerpoop' and 'blueprints' coming from?

Answer (score 5):

Tinkerpop Blueprints is a standard for Graph Database API.
It is a separate project, you can find all the details here:
http://www.tinkerpop.com/

OrientDB supports Tinkerpop Blueprints, so it is part of the dependencies.

If you download latest OrientDB version, you will find a jar file named blueprints-core-**.jar under the /lib directory. This jar contains the com.tinkerpop.blueprints package.

To get started with OrientDB in your java application, you will need at least orientdb-commons.jar, orientdb-client.jar and orientdb-core.jar, but I suggest you to import into your classpath all the orient-*.jar files

Answer (score 0):

try to import this libraries into your project

```
<properties>
   <orientdb.version>2.1-rc4</orientdb.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
      <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
      <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
      <artifactId>orientdb-client</artifactId>
      <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
      <artifactId>orientdb-object</artifactId>
      <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
      <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
      <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Nevertheless, I'm currently working on a java based orientdb wrapper, designed to be the most user friendly and easy to use as possible. We are using this on a large scale project in my company, you can take a look at it if you want.. it might help!

https://github.com/alonsod86/orientdb-graph-wrapper

Once you download it execute `mvn clean install` and import it in your project, just like this

```
<dependency>        
    <groupId>es.alonso</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-graph-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps!